# Is there way to pass touch event from one view to another?

Tags: react-native, touch-event

A have two layers with components on the screen. Upper layer is intercepting all touch events. I need the way to propagate those events to the below layer. Please, look the example below, for now only onUpperViewPressed is outputs. The desired behavior are both: onBellowViewPressed and onUpperViewPressed should be outputed when corresponding views are pressed.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
        
        <Text
          onPress={() => console.log('onBellowViewPressed')}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 100,
            left: 100,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          }}>
          Below view
        </Text>

        <Text
          onPress={() => console.log('onUpperViewPressed')}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          Upper view
        </Text>
      
      </View>
      
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/jJ1DQDMeR

**What I've already tried:**

- Tried to add '**zIndex**: 1' to 'below view', but in that case 'below view' lower view starts to intercept all events.
- Tried to play with **pointerEvents** with no luck.
- Also tried **react-native-touch-through-view**

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get it! when i click the text "bellow view" it outputs "onBellowViewPressed" when I click outside of it, it outputs "onUpperViewPressed".  Do you want when you click the "bellow view" to output both logs?

Comment: @MPN7 For now when I press first Text onUpperViewPressed outputs to the console instead of 'onBellowViewPressed'. The desired behavior: all views must to dispatch touch event.